# Adding Date Axis to BubbleChart in jqPlot

Tags: jqplot

Hi I am trying to add date to X-Axis in the bubble chart in jqplot, but x-axis is not getting plotted. below the jqplot script i am using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var arr = [['2008-07-30 8:00AM', 123, 1236, "Acura"], 
   ['2008-08-30 8:00AM',       92, 1067, "Alfa Romeo"], 
           ['2008-09-30 8:00AM', 104, 1176, "AM General"]];

plot1 = $.jqplot('chart2', [arr], {
    title: 'Transparent Bubbles',
    axes: {
        xaxis:{       
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
        }
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
            highlightAlpha: 0.8
        },
        shadow: true,
        shadowAlpha: 0.05
    }
});
});
```

please help me out in solving this. TIA.